# Is it possible to integrate this equation?

Tags: integration, polynomials, indefinite-integrals, exponentiation

I need to integrate left side of this equation

$$r \left( \left(B \, \mathrm{ln}\dfrac{r}{R_2} +D \right) ^ \dfrac{-a}{a+1} + \left(F \, \mathrm{ln}\dfrac{r}{R_2} +D \right) ^ \dfrac{-a+1}{a+1}\right)\mathrm{d}r = ...$$

Where contants are $B, D, R_2, a, F$. Is it possible to express on some way these parts with exponents? In order to integrate it is necessary to first do this, then to integrate.

Or do I need to integrate numerical?

Comment: It should be possible to integrate this expression, but that is not likely the question that you're asking.  I believe that you're interested in finding the indefinite integral of this expression as a closed form in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Try to split up the logarithm and notice that the powers are just a constant exponent. What is the context of the problem?

Comment: Since the constants don't really matter, it might be easier to ask if you can find an indefinite integral for $$\int r(a+\ln r)^b\,dr,$$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Comment: It is fluid mechanics problem, where r is radius.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=integrate+x*%28Power%5B%28B*ln%28Divide%5Bx%2CPower%5BR%2C2%5D%5D%29+%2B+D%29%2CDivide%5B-a%2Ca%2B1%5D%5D%2BPower%5B%28F*ln%28Divide%5Bx%2CPower%5BR%2C2%5D%5D%29+%2B+D%29%2CDivide%5B-a%2B1%2Ca%2B1%5D%5D%29

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes, it could be expressed as problem you wrote, but 
do you have instructions for solving?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Wolfram Mathematica does not give solution in form of elementary functions, it gives form where appear incomplete gamma function. How to calculate incomplete gamma function?